# PHP HTTP Guzzle client - How to parse a JSON Array using Guzzle Streams

Tags: php, guzzle

I want stream a big JSON array response using Guzzle client. What I want is process a JSON object one, or ten, or fifty at a time. I have read several times the Guzzle documentation (https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/psr7.html#streams), I have searched the web looking for a tutorial or solution, but nothing, I can't figure it out.
Somebody knows how to do it?

Comment: Post what you have already tried.

Comment: is the JSON array in a file which you want to stream?

Comment: No, from API endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a Guzzle built-in solution but unfortunately there is not. I finally handled it using a JsonCollectionParser.

Further reading:

- Using a parser: https://github.com/MAXakaWIZARD/JsonCollectionParser
- Coding your own parser: https://nenadzivanovic.in.rs/blog/2020/05/28/using-php-streams-to-encode-and-decode-large-json-collections/